# Cyrillic symbols in URL

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

App crashes with following url:

```
let jsonUrl = "http://api.com/алматы/events"
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let shotsUrl = NSURL(string: jsonUrl)
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(shotsUrl!)
```

Log:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

It's because of cyrillic symbols in url. How can I solve this issue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
let encodedUrl = jsonUrl.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet)
```

Answer (score 23):

**Swift 4**
Using String Extension
Create a swift file named **String+Extension.swift** and paste this code

```
import UIKit
extension String{
    var encodeUrl : String
    {
        return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
    }
    var decodeUrl : String
    {
        return self.removingPercentEncoding!
    }
}
```

and Use it like so: (*sample according to question*):

```
"http://api.com/алматы/events".encodeUrl
```

Comment: Tnx, it's very useful answer

Comment: most welcome. please do comment if have any more request. and send me the link. 
i have create bunch of xcode extension.. to make sure development easy and fast.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```swift
let apiHost = "http://api.com/"
let apiPath = "алматы/events"
let escapedPath = apiPath.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
let url = NSURL(string: "\(apiHost)\(escapedPath!)")
```

Obviously you should do something smarter than just force unwrap `escapedPath`.

Using the Wikipedia page for Swift as an example:
`https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_(язык_программирования)`

Becomes:

```
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)
```

Which when pasted into the browser takes you to the right page (and most browsers will conveniently render the UFT-8 characters for you).

Answer (score 4):

Non-ASCII characters (and many special characters) need to be escaped in a URL. Chrome and other browser do it automatically. And they unescape the URLs in the address bar for a nicer display.

So if you have a static URL, just paste it into the adressbar, press enter, selected the URL again, copy and paste it to your app:

So instead of:

```
let jsonUrl = "http://api.com/алматы/events"
```

You'll get:

```
let jsonUrl = "http://api.com/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B/events"
```

Comment: @aaisataev I provided a basic answer that should be enough for you to figure it out from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try [stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:) defined on NSString. You may see people suggesting `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`, but that method is deprecated in iOS 9.

There are also a few predefined `NSCharacterSet`s in Foundation, such as  `URLHostAllowedCharacterSet` and `URLPathAllowedCharacterSet`. Therefore, if you really have to parse the unescaped URL in code (using preprocessed URLs, mentioned in the accepted answer, is usually a much better idea), you can write a helper method like this:

```
import Foundation

func url(scheme scheme: String, host: String, path: String) -> NSURL? {
    let components = NSURLComponents()
    components.scheme = scheme
    components.host = host.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
    components.path = path.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet())
    return components.URL
}

// evaluates to http://api.com/%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BB%25D0%25BC%25D0%25B0%25D1%2582%25D1%258B/events
url(scheme: "http", host: "api.com", path: "/алматы/events")
```

Note that the above documentation mentions that

> This method is intended to percent-encode an URL component or subcomponent string, NOT an entire URL string.

That's because according [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), not all parts of an URL can be percent-encoded (e.g. `scheme` - http/https/etc.)

Answer (score -1):

in xamarin:

```
var uri = new Uri (url);
var nsurl = new NSUrl (uri.GetComponents (UriComponents.HttpRequestUrl, UriFormat.UriEscaped));
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (nsurl);
```

Answer (score -4):

URLs cannot contain Cyrillic characters. There are standards how to translate Cyrillic characters into valid URLs - you might find something if you search for "Punicode" (the P is intentional).

Comment: Look at this for example: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Арктическая_экспедиция_Грили No Punicode on Wikipedia. Percent escaped characters will be interpreted as UTF-8, as per the `NSURL` documentation.

Comment: "Punycode is intended for the encoding of labels in the Internationalized Domain Names in Applications (IDNA) framework, such that these domain names may be represented in the ASCII character set allowed in the Domain Name System of the Internet. " So what you are saying is only true for the domain part of the URL, not the rest.